# Не получается сравнить объекты внутри коллекции

Tags: java, коллекции

Добрый день!

Есть Фабрика по созданию различных сортов кофе(Арабика или Робуста).

Они в свою очередь наследуются(т.е. классы Arabica и Robusta) от абстрактного класса Coffee.

На данный момент реализовано создание объектов с помощью фабрики.

Потом надо засунуть эти объекты в коллекцию под названием Фургон кофе.

Отлично, все получается, созданные объекты добавляются в коллекцию CoffeeVan(это отдельный класс).

Теперь создаю класс CoffeeWeightComparator(хочу сортировать по весу).

```
public class CoffeeWeightComparator implements Comparator<Coffee> {
public int compare(Coffee o1, Coffee o2) {
    Double weight1 = o1.getWeight();
    Double weight2 = o2.getWeight();
    return weight1.compareTo(weight2);
}
}
```

Далее идёт метод Main

```
public class Runner {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CoffeeFactory arabica = CoffeeFactory.create(0);
    CoffeeFactory robusta = CoffeeFactory.create(1);
    CoffeeVan coffeeVan = new CoffeeVan(new ArrayList<CoffeeFactory>());
    coffeeVan.fillVan(arabica);
    coffeeVan.fillVan(robusta);
    System.out.println(coffeeVan.toString());
    Collections.sort(coffeeVan, new CoffeeWeightComparator());

}
}
```

И вот когда я вызываю сортировку в последней строке, он ругается на

> Wrong 1st argument type. Found: CoffeeVan, requid Coffee

Передавать кофе я не могу, т.к. коллекция находится в CoffeeVan, в классе Coffee просто создаются объекты.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ругается потому, что вы параметры в метод `sort` передаете некорректные:

```
public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Первым параметром должен быть список, а у вас `CoffeeVan` очевидно, им не является. Чтобы подобный код заработал нужно или изменить логику, или сделать `CoffeeVan` классом реализующим интерфейс `java.util.List`, или потомком одной из его реализаций:

```
 private static class CoffeeVan extends ArrayList<Coffee> {}
```

Comment: Получилось, только теперь он не добавляет в коллекцию.

Comment: вот так теперь должен выглядить метод добавления public void fillVan(Coffee coffee){
            this.add(coffee);
        }

Comment: Фургон уже является списком и надобность в дополнительном списке исчезает, поэтому в конструктор теперь ничего передавать не нужно.

Comment: В этой строке: coffeeVan.fillVan(arabica);
он ругается теперь на fillVan in CoffeeVan cannot be applied to CoffeeFactory

Comment: а зачем вы в fillVan передаете фабрику? Я не знаю, как у вас задумано, но обычно с помощью какой то фабрики создаются экземпляры определенного класса и потом уже с ними работают. (см ответ @iksuy) По логике в метод fillVan уже нужно передавать кофе.

Comment: Большое Спасибо Вам! Очень помогли!

Answer (score 4):

Конечно ругается, у вас в `sort` передается `CoffeeVan`, а компаратор определен для `Coffee`.

Список фабрик - очень сомнительная вещь. Вероятно вам нужно (или вы пытались сделать) что-то вроде такой иерархии:

```
class Coffee {/*...*/}

class Arabica extends Coffee {/*...*/}

class Robusta extends Coffee {/*...*/}

class CoffeeFactory {

    public enum CoffeeCode { ARABICA, ROBUSTA };

    public Coffee create(CoffeeCode cc){
        if(cc == CoffeeCode.ARABICA){
            return new Arabica();
        } else {
            return new Robusta();
        }
    }

}
```

Ну и ваш код из `main`:

```
Coffee arabica = CoffeeFactory.create(ARABICA);
Coffee robusta = CoffeeFactory.create(ROBUSTA);
List<Coffee> coffeeVan = new ArrayList<Coffee>();
coffeeVan.add(arabica);
coffeeVan.add(robusta);
Collections.sort(coffeeVan, new CoffeeWeightComparator());
```

**UPD**

Если вам нужно использовать именно `CoffeeVan`, то либо он должен реализовывать интерфейс `List<Coffee>`, либо осуществлять сортировку иным способом.

Comment: Получается CoffeeVan вообще не используется? Просто мне нужно именно что бы вся коллекция хранилась в CoffeeVan.
А так ваш код работает, Спасибо Вам большое, единственное что остается так это что делать с CoffeeVan, коллекция нужна именно там.

Comment: @D.Mark, обновил ответ

Comment: Большое Спасибо Вам! Задание решено!